# Load More After Coming to Bottom of UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

For my app I am using a "load more at bottom" property as below. It works fine actually; the only problem is that when a user reaches the buttom, while the load more function is working, to the user it seemes like the app is freezing for a while as there is no animation view like in the `UIRefreshcontrol`. How can I make the animation showing until the new data is loaded. I found some `UIBottomrefreshcontrol` properties as separate libraries, but they were all in Objective-c.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   refreshResults()

 }

 func refreshResults() {


    refreshPage = 40

    // here the query starts
}


func refreshResults2() {

     // here the query starts to add new 40 rows of data to arrays

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell,     forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == refreshPage-1 {
        refreshPage = refreshPage + 40

        refreshResults2()

    }
}
```

Comment: You can still use Objective-C code in a mostly Swift app. Or you can rewrite one of those libraries in Swift if you want.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` (i.e. spinner) to your UITableViewController.  Connect the outlet to the code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView!
```

Add a property to your `UITableViewController` to keep track that you're currently loading more data so that you don't try to do it twice:

```
var loadingData = false
```

Start the spinner animating and then call `refreshResults2()`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    if !loadingData && indexPath.row == refreshPage - 1 {
        spinner.startAnimating()
        loadingData = true
        refreshResults2()
    }
}
```

Have `refreshResults2()` run on a background thread.  This will allow your table to still move freely.  The animated spinner will tell the user that more data is coming.  Once your query returns, update the table data on the main thread.

```
func refreshResults2() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0)) {
        // this runs on the background queue
        // here the query starts to add new 40 rows of data to arrays

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            // this runs on the main queue
            self.refreshPage += 40
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            self.spinner.stopAnimating()
            self.loadingData = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got infinite loop and I'm not allowed to scroll after the five first ones already displayed. Looks like number of row got stuck to the first count definition... https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b5f06b7e394415f74e445693015ebde3

Answer (score 2):

> Swift 3 , Xcode 8

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let lastElement = dataSource.count - 1
    if !loadingData && indexPath.row == lastElement {
        spinner.startAnimating()
        loadingData = true
        loadMoreData()
    }
}
```

as per @vacawama async call in swift 3:-

```
func loadMoreData() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        // this runs on the background queue
        // here the query starts to add new 10 rows of data to arrays
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
             // this runs on the main queue
                self.spinner.stopAnimating()
                self.loadingData = false

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not make a difference, still problem persisted @AbdulKarim

Comment: Where do you place `spinner ` in the view? Below the prototype cell?

Comment: @Mirko spinner is in the view placed in UItableview and connected with IBOutlet