# How to hide refresh control in tableview when all data is loaded in swift 3?

Tags: swift, uirefreshcontrol

Iam using `UIRefreshControl()` in tableview to load more data from server when user pull to refresh. How can i hide the `UIRefreshControl()` or make user can not pull anymore when all the data is loaded. Thank for your helping !

Comment: have you searched on internet ? following any tutorial for using UIRefreshControl ?

Comment: Use "refreshControl.endRefreshing()" after complete your webservice call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425466/load-more-after-coming-to-bottom-of-uitableview  check this

Comment: refreshControl.endRefreshing() is only hide the indicator of the refreshcontrol. All i want here is that user can not pull to refresh anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.
    Objc C

```
[self.refreshControl removeFromSuperview];
self.refreshControl = nil;
```

Swift

```
self.refreshControl.removefromSuperview
self.refreshControl = nil
```

Comment: I have to remove the second line it works perfectly. Thank for your helping. Cheer. You save my time

Comment: Should be self.refreshControl.removefromSuperview()